# How are pages such as customer account login protected?

Tags: magento2, customer, controllers, action, logging

I'm looking through controllers, routes, sections, observers... and I can't find the method for protecting a page from non-logged in customers.

**How is this done officially?**

I may have found an answer in

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

If this is the method, could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Magento protected `loggedin` pages using `dispatch()` function of each Controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understood, there's basically two ways Magento does this.

The **first one is via a plugin**: `Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account` declared in `etc/frontend/di.xml` :

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="allowedActions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="create" xsi:type="string">create</item>
            <item name="login" xsi:type="string">login</item>
            <item name="logoutsuccess" xsi:type="string">logoutsuccess</item>
            <item name="forgotpassword" xsi:type="string">forgotpassword</item>
            <item name="forgotpasswordpost" xsi:type="string">forgotpasswordpost</item>
            <item name="resetpassword" xsi:type="string">resetpassword</item>
            <item name="resetpasswordpost" xsi:type="string">resetpasswordpost</item>
            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string">confirm</item>
            <item name="confirmation" xsi:type="string">confirmation</item>
            <item name="createpassword" xsi:type="string">createpassword</item>
            <item name="createpost" xsi:type="string">createpost</item>
            <item name="loginpost" xsi:type="string">loginpost</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount">
    <plugin name="customer_account" type="Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account" />
</type>
```

**Every account related controllers except the Address controllers extend the `Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount` abstract controller.**

And the plugin **uses `aroundDispatch` to check if the user is logged in or not**:

```
public function aroundDispatch(
    ActionInterface $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    RequestInterface $request
) {
    $action = strtolower($request->getActionName());
    $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $this->allowedActions) . ')$/i';

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->session->authenticate()) {
            $subject->getActionFlag()->set('', ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->setNoReferer(true);
    }

    $result = $proceed($request);
    $this->session->unsNoReferer(false);
    return $result;
}
```

As you can **see from the `di.xml` file**, the **plugin takes a number of arguments which are the actions allowed as a not logged in users**.

Then the plugin checks if the action is allowed, if it's not and the user is not logged in then it **sets the no dispatch flag so the action is not dispatched and the page can't be accessed**:

```
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->session->authenticate()) {
            $subject->getActionFlag()->set('', ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    }
```

The **second way is only affecting the Address related controllers**. Every address related controllers extend the abstract controller `Magento\Customer\Controller\Address`

If you check this controller `dispatch()` method you can see the following code that **checks if the user is logged and if the user is not logged in, it sets the no dispatch flag so the page cannot be accessed**:

```
public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
{
    if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate()) {
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', 'no-dispatch', true);
    }
    return parent::dispatch($request);
}
```

Regarding the redirection, when the `authenticate` method is called, it sets the redirect URL to the login page by default:

```
public function authenticate($loginUrl = null)
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }
    $this->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_createUrl()->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true]));
    if (isset($loginUrl)) {
        $this->response->setRedirect($loginUrl);
    } else {
        $arguments = $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrlParams();
        if ($this->_session->getCookieShouldBeReceived() && $this->_createUrl()->getUseSession()) {
            $arguments += [
                '_query' => [
                    $this->sidResolver->getSessionIdQueryParam($this->_session) => $this->_session->getSessionId(),
                ]
            ];
        }
        $this->response->setRedirect(
            $this->_createUrl()->getUrl(\Magento\Customer\Model\Url::ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN, $arguments)
        );
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What happens when the action isn't allowed? Redirect to login page or home?

Comment: @LM_Fielding see my edited answer

Comment: Raphael is the $loginUrl parameter where the user is redirected to when they complete authentication?

Comment: @LM_Fielding yes it is